# How can I change the text with a button click?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

When I click a button, I want the the string @string/dummy_content in fullscreen_content to change. How can I do that?

xml:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#2f4b66"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content">
```

button xml:

```
      <Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="printStarter"
                />
```

The Java function I would like to activate:

```
public void printStarter(View view) {

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

You can't change string resource at the run time

```
public void printStarter(View view) {    
   ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content)).setText("Your Text");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the reference of the TextView whose text you need to set. Here is the code:

```
public void printStarter(View view){
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    text.setText("Some text....");
}
```

You can't change string resource dynamically since it's a compiled resource.